# Using "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />" Rreturn Error:- The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, caml-query, caml

I have the following code inside my remote event reciever, the code will get all the folders and files under a specific folder:-

```
CamlQuery camlQuery6 = new CamlQuery();
   camlQuery6 = new CamlQuery();
   camlQuery6.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString() + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>";

   ListItemCollection collListItem6 = context.Web.GetList(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Library3").GetItems(camlQuery6);
   context.Load(collListItem6, items => items.Include(
          item => item.Id,
          item => item["FileDirRef"],
          item => item["Title"],
          item => item["DealStage"],
          item => item["DealName"],
          item => item["Fund"]
        ));
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

now the returned items will be around 150, but the library3 i am querying against contain more than 5500 items. so the above code is returing the folloiwng error:-

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the administrator.

so can anyone advice how i can overcome this issue? by modifying the query or adding indexed?
Thanks

Comment: Recommendation is to create index to overcome 5K threshold.https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/

Comment: @MatiurRahman yes i know but i can not create an index on `FileDirRef`

Comment: @willman i already read this article, but the approach mentioned will not work if i am querying against a non-indexed field. and in my case i am querying against the `FileDirRe` which can not be indexed..

Comment: You don't need an index field in your Query specifically for that technique to work. The whole point of adding a `<RowLimit>` parameter to your CAML is to stay under the list view threshold.  Then, you use `ListItemCollectionPosition` to retrieve the next chunk of items in a loop.  One thing not mentioned in that article is that you have to reference an indexed column at least somewhere in your query, so if nothing else, add `<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>` -- but this only works around the problem if you are also using `<RowLimit>`

Comment: @willman but i want to get the files and folders under specif folder, so in this case i will have to iterate over all the files and folders?

Comment: No, keep your query the same, but add the `<OrderBy>` and the `<RowLimit>` -- if you know you'll never get more than 500 results in that folder, you probably don't need to worry about `ListItemCollectionPosition`, but it essentially allows you do get results in 5000-item (or fewer) chunks to stay under the threshold.

Comment: @willman i did not get your point honestly .. you mean i can filter using the non-index column `FileDirRef` inside my query?

Comment: @willman one of the comments mentioned `non index column will not work in the caml query, in case if you need to include those columns, you will have to index those columns` and i can not index `FileDirRef`

Comment: The whole point of RowLimit is to get past that limitation.  I don't know the details of what that commenter was doing, but I have successfully used `RowLimit` and `ListItemCollectionPosition` to get items from lists far larger than 5000 with no indexed columns.

Comment: @willman so i will need to get the first bunch of 5000 items >> search if they are inside the related folder >> then loop through the second 5000 items >>  and so on?

Comment: No, your `<BeginsWith>`  query will still only get items that meet your criteria. The problem is, without an indexed column, SharePoint is trying to scan the entire list of 5500 items to see which ones meet your criteria, then failing due to the threshold. If you set a RowLimit, it will only search the first 5000 items for items that meet your criteria, and return those 150 or so items, problem is there may be items that meet your criteria in those last 500 items it didn't search, so you execute in a loop advancing `ListItemCollectionPosition`, which tells it to search the next chunk of items.

Comment: @willman so mainly i will have to scan all the files inside the library? is this correct? in the future this library might  expand and get 500,000 items.. so i will have to search all the files to get the ones which are under the related folder? are you sure there is no other way to do so?

Comment: The whole point of the <RowLimit> and ListItemCollectionPosition is to search large lists in chunks -- remember, that list scanning is happening on the server-side, and only returning you items that meet your criteria, but with large lists you cannot scan the whole thing at once, you have to do it in chunks.

Comment: @willman so can you provide a sample CAML query? as i am a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

So, if you google for "SharePoint CSOM Large Lists", you will find plenty of examples -- but the gist is that in order to query a large list while staying within the ListViewThreshold, you have to set a `RowLimit`, so that SharePoint doesn't try to scan the entire List in fell swoop, it will only scan the number of items specified by `RowLimit`.  But of course, in order for you to get all the correct results, you Do want it to eventually scan the whole list against your criteria, but if the list size exceeds the List View Threshold, then you have to do it in "chunks".  You set a `RowLimit` in your CAML, but then keep track of the returned `ListItemCollectionPosition`, and then execute the query again in a loop, telling SharePoint to scan the next `RowLimit` of items, starting from the previously left off `ListItemCollectionPosition`.

So, the two main things to keep in mind, is to modify your CAML to limit the number of rows scanned, but use a `do..while` loop to keep checking the next chunk of rows until you have checked the whole list.  The other caveat is that if you have no Indexed columns referenced anywhere in your query, then SharePoint has no way of keeping track of that Position, so the easiest thing to do is add `<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy>`.

The following should get you want you are looking for:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("weburl");
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle");

List list = context.Web.GetList(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Library3");
var foundListItems = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ListItem>();

camlQuery6 = new CamlQuery();
// The RowLimit tells SharePoint to only scan the next 1000 items
camlQuery6.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString() + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>";

do
{
    ListItemCollection collListItem6 = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    context.Load(collListItem6, items => items.Include(
          item => item.Id,
          item => item["FileDirRef"],
          item => item["Title"],
          item => item["DealStage"],
          item => item["DealName"],
          item => item["Fund"]
        ));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    // this line grabs the position from where SharePoint left off, 
    // so we can pass that in as the starting position the next time through the loop
    camlQuery6.ListItemCollectionPosition = collListItem6.ListItemCollectionPosition;
    foreach (ListItem listItem in collListItem6) // collect the items we found in this chuck of searched items
    {
        foundListItems.Add(listItem);
    }
}
while(camlQuery6.ListItemCollectionPosition != null) // collListItem6.ListItemCollectionPosition will be set back to null once we reached the end of the list

//Now we can do something with all the items we found
foreach (var listItem in foundListItems )
{
    // do something with the listItem
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but i got the same error "the attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator"

Comment: Lets try an experiment, I know that there are certain operators that will never work in a 5000+ item list, even with RowLimit -- I thought the only two that wouldn't work were `<Lte>` and `<Gte>`, but let's see if the problem is with `<BeginsWith>`. See what happens if you change the CAML to `"<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"`

Comment: i do not think i will be able to filter based on non0index columns...

Comment: Based on your other question, I think I was setting `ListItemCollectionPosition` incorrectly.  I just edited this answer, see if this works any better.